# different solution for z3 shell and java api

Tags: z3

I tried the same assumption in both z3 shell and java api. as follows:

```
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 32))

(assert (not (bvsle (bvadd x #xfffffff8) #x00000000)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

In z3 shell, the solution is: x = 9
But in z3 api, the solution is: x = 0x80000000
In my application, I prefer the shell result. 
So I wanna if I missed some option in API usage.

BTW. is there any option that I can use to control the solution value, I want some more reasonable values. But often Z3 give me some really big value looking like random value.

Answer (score 1):

*AFAIK*, the Model of a satisfiable formula can *be said* to be chosen at random in **z3**.

If by *reasonable value* you mean *small*, then you could in principle optimise over `x` with **z3** to ensure that the returned model sets `x` equal to `#x00000009`. **e.g.**

```
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 32))

(assert (not (bvsle (bvadd x #xfffffff8) #x00000000)))
(minimize x)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Of course that might have a *significant impact* on the time taken by the search on harder problems.

This is one of those situations in which setting a *timeout* over the optimisation search, and still being able to retrieve the model associated with the *best approximation* (if any) of the optimal solution, would be ideal. I don't know whether **z3** has this feature, though.

Comment: Yes, Z3 does support some forms of optimization, see e.g., http://rise4fun.com/Z3Opt/tutorial/guide

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the problem. We missed calling the reset() method of Solver after every solve, so the value of model is always big number. By calling reset() every time we solve a constraint, the value is what I expected.

Comment: @chenrui sounds like an implementation-reliant solution